# Cookie not allowing multiple key/value pairs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I've got a simple scheme for keeping a user logged in using a cookie.  I want the cookie to contain two name value pairs when i am done.  I've used this basic implementation before, I can't understand why it isn't working for me this time.

```
    protected void SetAuthCookie(string EventCode, string id)
    {


        SHA1 sha = SHA1.Create();
        byte[] data = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id));
        HttpCookie AuthCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }


        AuthCookie["eventcode"] = EventCode;
        AuthCookie["id"] = sBuilder.ToString();
        Response.Cookies.Add(AuthCookie);
    }
```

Here's what i've discovered so far: If I comment out "AuthCookie["eventcode"] = EventCode;"  then in my browser i see that MyCookie is left with value "id=foo".

Likewise, if I comment out "AuthCookie["id"] = sBuilder.ToString();" I see MyCookie is left with value "eventcode=foo".

What I want is MyCookie to have a value of "eventcode=foo&id=bar".  If i leave neither line commented out, however, In my browswer, i see that MyCookie has no\empty value.  What gives?

The only difference in previous implementations is thatI haven't processed the 'id' parameter - it was already a guid.  I think the fact that it is a cryptographically hashed string is a red herring,  because hard coding 'foo' as the value for cookie value for 'id' or 'eventcode' leads to the same outcome.  I may be wrong about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpCookie AuthCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
AuthCookie.Values["eventcode"] = EventCode;
AuthCookie.Values["id"] = sBuilder.ToString();
AuthCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
```

This should work, says [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?)

I've found Google Chrome to have a few weird issues with localhost/dev websites. Could this be the case?

Comment: I am using chrome on my localhost, I think you are on the money.  For example, if i change the key "id" to "_id" everything works the way i expect it to.